# Is there a way to disable jQuery scroll animation for some html anchors?

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I would like to have every href anchor smooth scrolling by default (this works!) ... and manually prevent some of them to be not.

Is there a smart way to do this? Maybe a "notscrollable" CSS class to target? How would it look like?

```
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    // Smooth scroll on anchor links
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash;
        var $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-20
        }, 900, 'swing', function() {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });

});
```

All html anchors are smooth scrolling with this script. Good!

Some specific anchors shouldn't be smooth scrollable. This is needed.

Comment: Change `$('a[href^="#"]')` to whatever selector you want that includes the ones you want, and doesn't include the ones you do not want.

Comment: You can use $('a[href^="#"]').not('.notscrollable').on('click', function(e) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a new class to `a` tags, for which you want to be disabled:

```
<a class="noscroll"  href="# ...
```

and change that to:

```
 $('a[href^="#"]').not(".noscroll").on(...
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello you can add custom attribute or class to anchor elements on which you do not need scroll.

For example:

```
<a href="#hello">click</a>
<a href="#hello" noscroll>no scroll</a>
```

and change code like this:

```
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
'use strict';

// Smooth scroll on anchor links
$('a[href^="#"]:not([noscroll])').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-20
    }, 900, 'swing', function() {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
```

});

Here the jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/maksim2099/7sky5gL4/1/). Best of luck, feel free to ask any questions